# Create dynamic Xpath

Tags: xpath, dynamic

I want to click on 'Select' where preceding block contains text, "Byron Test 20150904". This text is dynamic

[image: //I want to click on 'Select' where preceding block contains text, "Byron Test 20150904". This text is dynamic]

Comment: what text is dynamic? "Byron Test" or "20150904" or all ?

Comment: You should try to select the element by something specific(some attribute/state) else you can select any element of the same type if all elements are the same.

Comment: @luada Thanks for your suggestion. Its solved using following xpath where you change text " Byron Test 20150904"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error i find the answer

```
//div[@id='itOverview']/div[.//a[contains(text(),'Byron Test 20150904')]]/div/div[3]/div[2]/a
```